# How do i get values of a column based on another column python

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that ask for the Unique value and I will like to get another column based on those unique value.

Trying to get the colour in all_names

```py
raw_data={'Class':['A1','B1','C1','D1','A1'],
          'Name':['Harry','Christabel','Mel','Chris','Cherry'],
          'Color':['Red','Blue','Pink','Red','Red']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
all_names = df['Name'][df['Class']=='A1'].unique()
all_colour=df.loc[df['Colour'].isin(all_names)]
```

I have tried the code above but I am trying to get the color for Harry and Cherry which is red and red.

Comment: The dictionary was missing some but it has been well understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** If you simply want the color of Harry and Cherry do:

```
Color_Harry_Cherry=list(df.loc[[0,4],'Color'])
print(Color_Harry_Cherry)
```

Out:

```
['Red', 'Red']
```

**2** If you want to get the colors of the list `all_names` you could do this to do it without errors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data={'Class':['A1','B1','C1','D1','A1'],'Name':['Harry','Christabel','Mel','Chris','Cherry'],'Color':['Red','Blue','Pink','Red','Red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
all_names = df['Name'][df['Class']=='A1'].unique()
print(all_names)
i=0
colors = []
while i<len(df['Color']):
    if df.loc[df.index.values[i],'Name'] in all_names:
        colors = colors + list(df.loc[[df.index.values[i]],'Color'])
    i+=1
print(colors)
```

Out:

```
['Harry' 'Cherry']
['Red', 'Red']
```

**3 Why didn't your code work?**

Notice that `df['Color'].isin(all_names)` returns:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Color, dtype: bool
```

And the `loc` method, needs as arguments the index and the column where the value you want to select from the DataFrame is located. Because of this you received an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dataset is not in correct dictionary format. It should look like this :

```
raw_data={
    'Class':['A1','B1','C1','D1','A1'],
    'Name':['Harry','Christabel','Mel','Chris','Cherry'],
    'Color':['Red','Blue','Pink','Red','Red']
}
```

After that, you can continue subsetting your columns. Check this code :

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataset should look like this
raw_data={
    'Class':['A1','B1','C1','D1','A1'],
    'Name':['Harry','Christabel','Mel','Chris','Cherry'],
    'Color':['Red','Blue','Pink','Red','Red']
}

# Assign dataset into pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

# Get Harry's color
harry = df.loc[df["Name"] == "Harry", "Color"].unique()[0]

# Get Cherry's color
cherry = df.loc[df["Name"] == "Cherry", "Color"].unique()[0]

# Print them
print("Harry's color is %s" % harry)
print("Cherry's color is %s" % cherry)
```

That should work.